# How to stop Robot Framework suite execution on console error?

Tags: robotframework

Robot framework may show some errors to the console if e.g. it cannot find some file at some path. This is not test or suite related failures. This error just loggs to the console, but Robot Framework continues to execute suites and test after this kind of error. So my question is: **how can I change this default behavior and tell Robot Framework to stop execution if it finds this kind of errors?**

Maybe it can be some command line option or special tag. I searched in docs here https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#errors-and-warnings and did not find any info about that. Am I missing something?

Example of such error:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\Projects\project\suites\02__app\05__d\editing.robot': Resource file '..\..\..\resources\keywords\attribute.resource' does not exist.
Suites.App.d.Editing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the option `--exitonerror` is the command line option you are looking for.

Comment: Nope, that is not worked. I assume because this error not actually a test failure or keyword failure.

Comment: Apologies. I posted the wrong argument. I've tested the edited answer above with my blah.txt resource :) and it works. --exitonerror.